# How to find repeating count of last digits of powers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The last digits of powers of a number repeats. For example the last digits of powers of 2 repeat in a cycle of 4, 8, 6, 2, 4, 8, 6, 2 and the last digits of powers of 9 repeat in a cycle of 1, 9, 1, 9. That is for 2, the repeat count is 4 and for 9 it is 2. In fact, the repeat count of all numbers ending with 2 is 4 and 9 is 2 which can be proved with binomial theorem. Hence the repeat count of any decimal number can be easily calculated from the repeat counts of first 9 numbers.

But I am looking for a solution to find repeat count of numbers with larger base/radix than decimal. Hence maintaining a complete lookup table is hard. Also is there a solution to find the repeat count if we consider n last digits instead of 1? In short, given a number, its base and howmany last digits, is it possible to find the repeat count?

So far I found Chinese Remainder Theorem and Euler’s Theorem to find last digits. But I couldn’t find a way through it to find the count. I have only basic knowledge in mathematics. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Do you already know that you can find the last $k$ digits of the powers of $p$ in the basis $b$ by $p^i\text{ mod } b^n$?

Comment: @M.Winter Yes. If I understood it correctly, any number mod $base^k$ is the definition of last k digits. But no idea how to find their repeat count.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you want to find the last $k$ digits of the powers of $p$ in base $b$. At first, define

$$B=\frac{b^n}{\gcd(b^n,p)}.$$

Now $B$ and $p$ are coprime and the "repeating count" of $p^i\pmod {b^n}$ is equal the one of $p^i\pmod{B}$. The term *coprime* is important here because now we can consider $p$ an element of the multiplicative unit group $\Bbb Z_B^\times$. The period you are looking for is called the *order* of $p$ in $\Bbb Z_B^\times$.

If I am not mistaken, then some cryptographic procedures are based on the fact that such an order is *really hard* to find. You might therefore be out of luck. Look for example on this page about [Shore's factorization algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) which works on quantum computers and reduces integer factorization to *order-finding* which seems to be unfeasible on regular computers.

However, if your modulus $B$ is not *too large*, you can brute-force your answer. It suffices to use only numbers $\le B^2$ (or even $\le B$) when applying modular exponentiation. For example, compute the order of $p=7$ in base $10$:

\begin{align}
7 &\equiv 7\pmod {10}\\
7\cdot 7=49 &\equiv 9\pmod {10}\\
7\cdot 9=63 &\equiv 3\pmod {10}\\
7\cdot 3=21 &\equiv 1\pmod {10}\\
\end{align}

and then it repeats because we reached $1$ (and it will always reach $1$ because $B$ and $p$ are coprime, and this can be used for "efficient" brute-force strategies because you do not have to remember the other numbers). So the "repeating count" is $4$. In the worst case the period is $B$ and you will have to do all $B$ steps. Then $p$ is said to generate $\Bbb Z_B^\times$. There are some results on [generators of such groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group) which might help you.